# How to list committed git files per size?

Tags: git, git-svn, tortoisegit

Is it possible to list the set of committed files in a git repository, per file size?

I am using TortoiseGit under windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

You might have to fall back to the command line for this kind of search.

See if an approach like the one described in "[Finding and Purging Big Files From Git History](http://naleid.com/blog/2012/01/17/finding-and-purging-big-files-from-git-history)" can work:

```
git gc && git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx | egrep "^\w+ blob\W+[0-9]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+$" | sort -k 3 -n -r > bigobjects.txt
```

You might need to install [GoW (Gnu On Windows)](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) for the sort command.
The `egrep` command is part of a [regular msysgit distribution](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=3&q=portable&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount).